# After installing perforce and eclipse plugin, team->share option doesn't appear

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perforce

I have eclipse installed in my Mac Pro (OS X). I installed Perforce server on my own  machine and then installed Eclipse Plugin for perforce. All seems to be working fine except for the face that I don't have the option: "team->share"! Under team i just have patch. I have even added my perforce server in Perforce perspective!
could someone please help?
cheers
Ali

Comment: Did you have the option to set up a workspace at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. The problem was that I was using JDK 5 to start Eclipse.
I started Eclipse using JDK 6 (see below command line) and it worked.

```
D:\apps\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "D:\apps\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javaw.exe"
```